# Alternativoj por rolvorteto plus i-verbo

Tags: grammar, language-evolution

Laŭ [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/kun_rolvortetoj.html), estas “tabuo” uzi i-verbon post rolvorteto krom la 4 specifaj rolvertetoj *por*, *anstataŭ*, *krom* kaj *sen*. En tiu priskribo sekvas rekomendoj por anstataŭigi specifajn oftajn rolvortetojn. Kaj ŝajne la baza alternativo se nenio alia eblas estas aliformigi la i-verbon al verbeca o-vorto. Tamen mi trovas tiujn rekomendojn tute ne kontentigaj.

Ekzemple en [alia respondo](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/891/13) mi nature kaj senpense skribis la jenan frazon:

> uzi *fratoj* por priskribi grupon kiu enhavas virinojn similus al nomi ilin *viroj*

La rolvorteto *al* ne estas en la rango de tiuj 4 permesitaj, do ŝajne mi falis en la tabuan kaptilon. *Al* ne estas en la rekomendoj de PMEG, do supozeble mia nura alternativo estus io kiel:

> […] similus al nomado de ili *viroj*

Oni ne povus simple diri *nomo* por la ago ĉi tie ĉar tio jam havas alian signifon.

En [alia situacio](http://amara.org/en/videos/IgDGyYCJhooe/eo/1431125/) mi volis diri la jenan frazon:

> Ne temas pri subite kaj ŝoke ĉesi sed pri demandi sin kiel oni povas demamigi sin de tiu tre dependiga substanco.

La rekomendo por *pri* en PMEG estas ke oni kutime simple forlasas la rolvorteton. Sed en ĉi tiu okazo tio ne funkcius ĉar “temas ĉesi” ne havas sencon.

Ĉi tiu ekzemplo trafas apartan kaptilon menciitan en [la subo de la PMEGa artikolo](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/kun_rolvortetoj.html#j-tr3) ke la i-verbo devus havi la saman sencan subjekton kiel la ĉefa verbo. Tamen se oni uzus verbecan o-vorton ĝi iĝus ĉi tiu malbelaĵo:

> Ne temas pri subita kaj ŝoka ĉeso sed pri demando de oni [aŭ si?] kiel oni povas […]

La priskribo de la tabuo en PMEG ŝajnas malkomforta ĉar ĝi diras ke tiaj uzoj estus tute logikaj kaj ĝi ne donas veran kialon por la malpermeso. Laŭ mia scio aliaj lingvoj kiel la franca kaj la angla ne havas tiun malpermeson, do kial nia teorie pli fleksebla lingvo havus ĝin?

Do, mi efektive havas kvar demandojn:

1. Ĉu estas nur mi kiu trovas la o-verban solvon malbela?
2. Ĉu iu havas aliajn proponojn por kiel elturniĝi de miaj du ekzemploj?
3. [PMEG mencias](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/kun_rolvortetoj.html#j-bb7) ke ĉi tiu situacio povos ŝanĝiĝi laŭ la evoluo de la lingvo. Kiel estas la stato de ĉi tiu evoluo? Ĉu oni ofte trovas ekzemplojn de tiaj uzoj de i-verboj en la moderna lingvo?
4. Ĉu iu scias la originon de la tabuo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Mi ne malŝatas la uzadon de substantivoj en ĉi tiaj frazoj, fakte mi eĉ iomete preferas la sonon, sed mi komprenas viajn sentojn.

2) Mi sugestas frazojn ankoraŭ malbelajn sed iom pli zamenhofecajn:

> *Uzo de* fratoj *en priskribo de grupo kiu enhavas virinojn similus al nomado ilin* viroj.
>
> *Ne temas subita kaj ŝoka ĉeso, sed demandado al si kiel demamigi sin de...*

Se vi preferas infinitivojn, provu aldoni *kiel*:

> *Ne temas, kiel subite kaj ŝoke ĉesi, sed kiel sin demamigi de...*

3) Mi ne certas, sed mi neniam konsideris ĉi tion grava problemo, kaj mi konjektas ke aliaj esperantistoj apenaŭ konscias ke diskuto ekzistas.

4) Laŭŝajne, la origino estis Zamenhof mem:

> Kiel ni diras *«mi vidis lin sana»* (= *«ke li estas sana»*) tiel laŭ mia opinio ni povas ankaŭ diri *«mi vidis lin kuri»* (= *«ke li kuras»*), *«mi aŭdis lin paroli»* (= *«ke li parolas»*); sed la esprimojn *«li faris ĉion sen ridi»* aŭ *«li restis du tagojn sen manĝi»* mi ne konsilus al vi uzi. Prepozicion antaŭ verbo mi konsilus uzi nur en okazo de neceseco, se alie ni ne povas bone esprimi nian penson. Sed anstataŭ *«sen ridi»* aŭ *«sen manĝi»* ni povas ja tre bone diri *«sen rido»*, *«sen manĝo»* aŭ *«neniom ridante»*, *«nenion manĝante»*.

Tio estas lia *Lingva Respondo 20-a, La Revuo*, Junio 1907.

La ĉefa problemo, mi kredas, estas ke ekzistas okazoj en kiuj oni povas miskompreni la prepozicion kiel prefikso, ekz. *pri-labori, sen-ordigi, anstataŭ-iĝi,* ktp.

Answer (score 4):

Interesan demandon vi levis. Mi provas iomete respondi aŭ almenaŭ kontribui al la diskuto.

1. Ankaŭ mi ne tiom ŝatas la o-verban solvon. Kutime mi preferas la solvon forlasi la rolvorteton. Ekzemple

> Mi ĝojas pri via ĉeesto kaj ĝojas vidi vin.

La problemo en via ekzemplo kun "temi" estas, ke mankas al vi la subjekto de la sekvaj i-vortoj. Verŝajne tial ankaŭ la o-vorta solvo ŝajnas tiel malbela.

2. Mi pensas, ke bona solvo estas la truko kun "tio ke" + subfrazo:

> Ne temas pri tio, ke oni subite ĉesas kaj demandas sin ...

Se oni estas tre kuraĝa oni povas eĉ supozi ke "tio" estas subkomprenata:

> Ne temas pri, ke oni subite ĉesas kaj demandas sin ...

sed tio jam estas iomete riska.

3. Mi iam jam diskutis dum SES kun aliaj instruistoj pri la uzo de "pri + i-vorto" kaj ni diris, ke ĝi jes fariĝas pli ofta, sed tamen oni ne instruu ĝin aŭ instruu ke ĝi estas erara.
4. Mi ne scias, sed mi povas diveni: Oni supozas, ke la baza regulo estas ke rolvorteto + i-verbo ĝenerale ne eblas. La esceptoj eble venas de tio, ke ili aperas en la Ekzercaro (parto de la Fundamento) aŭ estas sufiĉe multaj Zamenhofaj citaĵoj de ili, ke oni ne povas konsideri ilin eraraj.

Answer (score 4):

1. Mi multe uzas Twitter, kaj se mi povas skribi *Temas pri manĝi pomojn* anstataŭ *Temas pri manĝado de pomoj*, mi faros tion. La unua frazo estas pli mallonga do pli oportuna. Mi ne vidas riskon de konfuzo en la unua frazo. Mi simple imitas la uzon de "pri" fare de aliaj Esperantistoj en tiu medio. Antaŭ unu jaro, mi diligente evitis uzi i-verbon post "pri", sed mi iom post iom imitis la aliajn kaj forlasis tiun mensan ŝarĝon.
2. Mi ne vere vidas alternativojn sufiĉe bonajn laŭ mi.
3. La situacio verŝajne evoluis por "permesi" la uzon de pli da vortetoj. Legu la suban lingvan respondon de Zamenhof. Li prezentas "anstataŭ" kaj "por" kiel apartajn rolvortetojn, sed nun oni ofte faras tion por "sen" kaj "antaŭ", kaj neniu plu plendas.
4. Ĝi verŝajne estas tre malnova. [Jam en 1908 Zamenhof respondis al pria demando](https://tekstaro.com/pl/prenitutantekston.pl?nomo=lingvaj-respondoj#lingvaj-respondoj-resp-128), en kiu li diras ke tio estas malpermesata sed jam enkondukas esceptojn.

> ### Pri prepozicio antaŭ infinitivo :
>
> **Ĉiu prepozicio, laŭ sia logika esenco, povas esti uzata nur antaŭ substantivo.** Sekve se antaŭ vorto, kiu havas verban sencon, ni
> deziras uzi prepozicion, ni devas doni al tiu verbo senca vorto la
> formon de substantivo; ekzemple: anstataŭ "kun saluti", "sen respondi"
> ni devas diri "kun saluto", "sen respondo". **Se la vortoj "por" kaj
> "anstataŭ" estas uzataj kun la infinitivo, ili tute ne prezentas ian
> escepton, sed la kaŭzo de tia uzado estas alia, nome: la vortoj "por"
> kaj "anstataŭ", uzataj antaŭ infinitivo, havas la sencon ne de pura
> prepozicio, sed preskaŭ de konjunkcio**, kaj en tiuj okazoj la uzado
> de substantivo apud ili estas ne ebla; ekzemple, en la frazo "anstataŭ
> stari li sidas" ni ne povas anstataŭigi la formon "stari" per "staro",
> dum ĉe ĉiu alia prepozicio pura ni ĉiam povas uzi la verbosencan
> vorton en formo de substantivo (ekzemple, "sen ia diro" anstataŭ "sen
> ion diri").