# Kial oni evitas "prepozicio + infinitivo aŭ KE"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, prepositions

Mi aŭdis, ke la esprimoj  "prepozicio + infinitivo" kaj "prepozicio + ke" ne estas rekomendindaj ekskluzive de kelkaj esceptoj (por, sen, krom kaj anstataŭ). Ĉu oni evitas tiajn esprimojn nur pro tradicia kialo aŭ pro logika problemo? Mi suspektas, ke ili havas logikan problemon, kiun mi ankoraŭ ne trovis, sed tiam mi ankaŭ interesiĝas pri diferenco inter la esceptoj kaj la aliaj prepozicioj.

Comment: Bonvenon al Stack Exchange! Ĉi tiu demando pri la temo verŝajne havas kelkajn respondojn kiuj povas helpi vin. https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/921/alternativoj-por-rolvorteto-plus-i-verbo/

Comment: @Neil Roberts Dankegon pro la informo! Mi legos ĝin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ĉu oni evitas tiajn esprimojn nur pro tradicia kialo aŭ pro logika problemo?

Laŭ [la PMEG-ĉapitro «I-verboj kun rolvortetoj»](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/kun_rolvortetoj.html) jam ligita en la demando [Alternativoj por rolvorteto plus i-verbo](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/921/1576) menciita de Neil [en komento](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/6699/kial-oni-evitas-prepozicio-infinitivo-a%C5%AD-ke#comment7399_6699), **ne estas logika problemo**:

> Uzado de aliaj rolvortetoj [ol *por*, *anstataŭ*, *krom* kaj eble *sen*] antaŭ I-verbo **ne estas mallogika**, sed povas krei miskomprenojn pro la malkutimeco.

Ĉu "malkutimeco" signifas, ke la ne-uzo estas *tradicia*? Eble. Tamen, PMEG ne mencias kiajn miskomprenojn tia uzo povus kaŭzi.

[Lingva respondo de Zamenhof el la jaro 1908](https://tekstaro.com/pl/prenitutantekston.pl?nomo=lingvaj-respondoj#lingvaj-respondoj-resp-128) (ankaŭ menciita en [tiu respondo](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/924/1576) al la demando [Alternativoj por rolvorteto plus i-verbo](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/921/1576)) parolas pri "logika esenco" sed esence indikas, ke tia uzo estus negramatika:

> Ĉiu prepozicio, laŭ sia logika esenco, povas esti uzata nur antaŭ *substantivo*.

> […] mi ankaŭ interesiĝas pri diferenco inter la esceptoj [*por*, *sen*, *krom* kaj *anstataŭ*] kaj la aliaj prepozicioj.

Laŭ tiu lingva respondo, "por" kaj "anstataŭ" estas en tiaj uzoj uzataj **ne vere kiel propozicio** sed kiel **konjunkcio** (kaj do eĉ tute ne estas esceptoj):

> Se la vortoj “por” kaj “anstataŭ” estas uzataj kun la infinitivo, ili tute ne prezentas ian escepton, sed la kaŭzo de tia uzado estas alia, nome: la vortoj “por” kaj “anstataŭ”, uzataj antaŭ infinitivo, havas la sencon ne de pura prepozicio, sed preskaŭ de konjunkcio, kaj en tiuj okazoj la uzado de substantivo apud ili estas ne ebla; ekzemple, en la frazo “anstataŭ stari li sidas” ni ne povas anstataŭigi la formon “star*i*” per “star*o*”, […]

Interese, iu lingva respondo (alie ol PMEG) tute ne mencias "krom", krom implike kiel parto de la grupo "**ĉiu** alia prepozicio *pura*":

> […] dum ĉe ĉiu alia prepozicio *pura* ni ĉiam povas uzi la verbosencan vorton en formo de substantivo […]

Kaj "sen" ĝi eĉ mencias kiel ekzemplo por montri kiel uzi verbecan substantivon anstataŭe:

> […] (ekzemple, “sen ia dir*o*” anstataŭ “sen ion dir*i*”).

Do eble oni povus konstati, ke i-verbo post prepozicio daŭre «ne eblas» / ne estas permesata, sed ke la lingvo intertempe evoluis tiel, ke pli kaj pli vortoj, kiujn oni antaŭe konsideris nur prepoziciojn, (certe "krom" kaj "sen") estas nun uzataj ankaŭ kiel (kaj parte konsiderataj) konjunkcioj.