# Kiel oni analizas "antaŭ ol", "post kiam" k.s.?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

En [mia lasta demando](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/6699/), mi lernis, ke teorie nur substantivo povas aperi post prepozicio. Sed tiam, kiel oni klarigas esprimon "antaŭ ol", "post kiam" k.s.? (En la vortaro, kiun mi ofte konsultas, ambaŭ aperas kiel konjunkcio tute kvazaŭ estus unu vorto. Ĉu tio sugestas, ke vortoj ne estas gramatike divideblaj en tiuj esprimoj?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La konstato en [la respondo de das-g](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/6701/1576) koncernas demandon, ĉu verbo aŭ ĉu substantivo post prepozicio. Tio neniel malebligas alispecajn vortojn.

"Antaŭ" kaj "post" estas prepozicioj, kiuj ne mem povas roli kiel frazenkondukiloj, alivorte enkonduki subfrazon. Ĉi tial oni aldonas la konjunkcion "ol" resp. la subjunkcion "kiam" (rimarku, ke "kiam" povas havi ankaŭ aliajn rolojn) por kunigi tempan subfrazon al la reston de la kompleta frazo.

- Antaŭ lia alveno ni manĝis. → Antaŭ ol li alvenis, ni manĝis.

La ago de la subfrazo (alveno) okazis antaŭ la ago de la ĉeffrazo (manĝado).

- La kverelo komenciĝis post lia foriro → La kverelo komenciĝis, post kiam li foriris.

La ago de la ĉeffrazo (komenciĝo) okazis post la ago de la subfrazo (foriro).

Comment: Nu, la Z.-a lingva respondo de 1908 citita en [mia respondo](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/6701/1576) al [Kial oni evitas "prepozicio + infinitivo aŭ KE"](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/6699/1576) ja asertas: «**Ĉiu prepozicio**, laŭ sia logika esenco, povas esti uzata **nur antaŭ _substantivo_**.» Sed eble tio ne (plu?) ĝustas.

Comment: Ial ĉi tiu temo ŝajnas aperi nun samtempe sur multaj forumoj. Mi ne certas, sed mi suspektas, ke en la lingvoj, kiujn Z konis, nur kelkaj prepozicoj povas havi alian ol substantivon post si. PMEG konstatas, ke "tradicie nur por, anstataŭ kaj krom estas akceptataj" sed daŭras, ke "uzado de aliaj rolvortetoj antaŭ I-verbo ne estas mallogika, sed povas krei miskomprenojn pro la malkutimeco". Do la lingvo ŝanĝiĝis de la tempo de Z.

Comment: Moderna analizo supre prezentita estas komprenebla, sed la Zamenhofa vidpunkto estas ankoraŭ ne-komprenebla al mi. Eĉ li uzis tiujn esprimojn en siaj verkoj kvankam "konjunkcieca uzo" ne plu validas. (Se li analizus tian prepozicion kiel konjunkciecan, la sekvanta frazenkondukilo estus tute superflua).

Comment: Leginte viajn respondojn, mi nun interpretas Z-an aserton nur en kunteksto de la diskuto "substantivo aŭ infinitivo" ĉar klare li ne celas malhelpi, ekzemple, ke adjektivo aperas tuj post prepozicio. Sed se li pensis tion tute regula aŭ laŭgramatika, li ĉiam povis uzi "prepozicio + ke + plena (sub)frazo" anstataŭ ke li permesis la ŝajnajn esceptojn. Estas ankoraŭ enigme.

Comment: Mi rezonas sekve. Kaj "antaŭ" kaj "post" povas montri lokon aŭ tempon, ekz. pri loko "antaŭ domo", "post vojkruco"(\*). Por montri ke temas pli tempo, oni aldonu plian vorton, t.e. "antaŭ ol" resp. "post kiam". (*) Kvankam "post + loko" eblas, oni pli kutime uzas "malantaŭ + loko" kaj uzas "post" nur kun tempo.

Comment: Ĉu do \*«post **ke** tagmezo» kaj \*«antaŭ **ol** hodiaŭ»? Laŭ mi ne. Vi pravas, ke "post ke" kaj "antaŭ ol" nur aperas en la pri-tempa uzo, @JuhaMetsäkallas, sed ŝajnas ke eĉ en ĝi, nur se la tempo-indiko estas per-verba.

Comment: Certe "post la tagmezo" taŭgas, sed ne kiel enkondukilo al subfrazo. Certe "Post kiam ni tagmanĝis…" taŭgas, tio jam havas frazenkondukilon, sed ne "post ke tagmezo". Pri tiu perverbeco… Vi pravas, ni jam havas tiujn "Antaŭ lia alveno…." kaj "Antaŭ ol li alvenis,…."